# Spring boot @RequestMapping annotation

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, angular, spring-boot, angular2-template

I am developing an Angular2 + Spring Boot application and as for now I have:
Backend: 1 @RestController with methods annotated with @RequestMapping, eg.

```
@RequestMapping("/main")
public Band[] main(@RequestParam(value="numberOfBands", required=false, defaultValue="3") int numberOfBands) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {          
    return random(numberOfBands);
}
```

Frontend: app.routing.ts, which redirects to '/main'
`{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'main',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },`
Upon initialization, my main.component.ts sends request to spring and gets an array of objects as response; The component looks like this:

```
export class MainComponent  {
  bands: Band[];
  errorMessage: string;
  constructor(private bandService: BandService){
    //this.bands = new Array(3);
    bandService.getRandomBands(3)
    .subscribe(
       bands => this.bands = bands,
       error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }
}
```

When going to `http://localhost:8090/` the app redirects to `/main` and the bands are properly passed and parsed by component. But whenever I try to reload the page `http://localhost:8090/main` I only get plain JSON, which looks like my component is not properly initializing.
I want spring boot to ignore the path in address bar, so it would be relevant only to client side exclusively.
The question is: is it a problem on the server side or is it me somehow initializing my components in an unappropriate way?

**UPDATE**
I've added prefix "/api" to all my @RequestMappings and added a filter, which looks like follows ('equals' is just to test out the functionality):

```
if(requestURI.equals("/main")){
        RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = httpServletRequest.getRequestDispatcher("/");
        requestDispatcher.forward(req, res);
    }
    chain.doFilter(req, res);
```

After that, the forwarding process went as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refreshing will always send a request to the server. Put all your REST API backend under a specific path, like `/api/...` for example, so that "fake" URLs used by the angular application don't clash with real URLs of your backend.

Then configure a filter in order to forward all the requests to those "fake" angular URLs to `/index.html`.

So a request to `/main` will be intercepted by your filter, which will forward to index.html. The angular application will start. the router will go to the route for `/main`. The component will send an AJAX request to `/api/main`. This request will **not** be forwarded to /index.html by the filter, so the Spring REST controller will handle it and serve the JSON.

Comment: wouldn't it make spring return null as the view and as a consequence the client will not be initialized ?

Comment: You mean, when the filter forwards to index.html? Can you clarify what you're asking?

Comment: I've tried to follow your answer, but when spring boot app redirects the request to index.html, there's no requestMapping for that value. So I added that requestMapping method, which returns void, but since the returned view is null, the angular app is not initialized.

Comment: I never said to redirect to index.html. I said to **forward** to /index.html. If you want more help, edit your question, post your code, and explain what the problem is, with all the necessary details.